# spring-data-elasticsearch - Jackson can't serialize using global configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, jackson, jhipster, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm developing a project using ElasticSearch and I'm having some problems with serialization/deserialization with Jackson. My project was created using JHipster, so, I'm using spring to store my entity to the database and to index in ElasticSearch. All entities and other objects can be (de)serialized with Jackson, except when I try to add it to ES.
This is my global configuration for Jackson:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
        SimpleModule timeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
        timeModule.addSerializer(OffsetDateTime.class, JSR310DateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
        timeModule.addSerializer(ZonedDateTime.class, JSR310DateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
        timeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, JSR310DateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
        timeModule.addSerializer(Instant.class, JSR310DateTimeSerializer.INSTANCE);
        timeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, JSR310LocalDateDeserializer.INSTANCE);
        SimpleModule geoModule=new GeoModule();
        geoModule.addSerializer(Point.class, PointSerializer.INSTANCE);
        geoModule.addDeserializer(Point.class, PointDeserializer.INSTANCE);
        return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
            .findModulesViaServiceLoader(true)
            .modulesToInstall(timeModule,geoModule);
    }
}
```

This configuration works fine, except when I try add an entity to ES, for example, `PointSerializer` is never called. The only way I can see this serializer running (and consequently indexing correctly) for ES is adding `@JsonSerialize(using = PointSerializer.class)` to the field. Why is it happening and how can I configure it globally?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Spring Data elasticsearch doesn't utilize the default spring `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` for this. Per default this configuration is used:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/DefaultEntityMapper.java

... which you can overwrite by providing some custom object mapper as described here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Custom-ObjectMapper

Here you can of course directly use your Jackson ObjectMappers. For more details, have a look at this issue at the jhipster github repo:

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2241#issuecomment-151933768

Comment: FYI: the first link is broken and the second one is outdated (they doesn't use Jackson anymore)